# Angular 1.0.7 ng-if alternative

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a paragraph view at my application, where every 5 items display in a block, one under each other, and the next five in the next block;

Example:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
 <div style="display:inline-block">
   <div style="display:block">1.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">2.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">3.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">4.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">5.-----</div>
 </div>

 <div style="display:inline-block">
   <div style="display:block">6.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">7.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">8.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">9.-----</div>
   <div style="display:block">10.-----</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So basically I need to do something ugly like 2 nested iterations, one advancing 5 elements at a time, and the other 1 element at a time.

Or an ng-if directive which is not available at the Angular version that I use.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use one `ng-repeat` to achieve it (without `ng-if`). Try something like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div style="display:inline-block" ng-show="$index % 5 == 0">
        <div style="display:block">{{items[$index+0].content}}</div>
        <div style="display:block">{{items[$index+1].content}}</div>
        <div style="display:block">{{items[$index+2].content}}</div>
        <div style="display:block">{{items[$index+3].content}}</div>
        <div style="display:block">{{items[$index+4].content}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kpgbx/

Comment: Doesn't the diffult ng-show/hide onlytoggles the CSS visibility of the element?

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Back to your original question. Why do you think using 2 repeaters is ugly?

Comment: What happens items is a function?, doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Any way to break a new line every 15 items?
Tried wrapping everything with another div with ng-show="($index +1) % 15 == 0", but no luck

Comment: Not such a good solution my friend, since I connot apply any filters to the results